# Перенос системной базы postgres

Tags: linux, postgresql

Всем привет. Знающие люди подскажите. Столкнулся с переносом базы данных с PostgreSQL 9.6 на 12-ю версию. Все пользовательские базы перенес и это проблем не составило, но возник вопрос. Как правильно перенести системную бд postgres со всеми расширениями, схемами, вьюхами. Т.е. полный перенос. Кто-то сталкивался с подобной ситуацией, подскажите как правильно поступить.

Comment: пробовали по классике? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/migration.html  - то есть, через pg_dumpall ?

Comment: а что вы имеете в виду под "системную бд postgres"? Базу с именем postgres, создаваемую автоматически при initdb? Переносится так же как любая пользовательская.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос переноса был решен с помощью `pg_dumpall -g`. Все остальное было установлено вручную, т.к. необходимо было все переделать под 12-ю версию.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/573956)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, вполне себе ответ. только лишнее можно удалить.